# How to collect into a pandas dataframe a set of documents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a directory full of `txt` documents:

```
.
├── file.txt
├── file.txt
├── file.txt
...
├── file.txt
└── file.txt
```

How can I read into a pandas dataframe all the documents?, in other words my objective is to store in a pandas dataframe object some documents like this (*):

```
    id  text_blob
0   file_name.txt   Lore lipsum dolor done
1   file_name.txt   Lore lipsum ...
2   file_name.txt   dolor ...
3   file_name.txt   lore lipsum lore ...
4   file_name.txt   dolor...
```

So far I tried the below code. However, it is not pythonic and I have some formating mistakes (e.g. space issues, `'"`, formating.):

```
import glob, os, csv, argparse, sys

def retrive(directory_path):
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, '*.txt'))):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            important_stuff = f.read().splitlines()
            oneline = [' '.join(important_stuff)]
            yield filename.split('/')[-1] + ', ' +str(oneline).strip('[]"')

def trans(directory,directory2):
            test = tuple(retrive(directory))
            with codecs.open(directory2,'w', encoding='utf8') as out:
                csv_out=csv.writer(out, delimiter='|')
                csv_out.writerow(['name','text_blob'])
                for row in test:
                    csv_out.writerow(row.split(', ', 1))


input_d = '../in'
out_d = '../out'



trans(input_d,out_d)
```

Comment: I've no idea what you expect the results to look like.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks for the help. I expect to have inside a pandas dataframe all the documents. As you can see in (*), the pandas dataframe is conformed of the name of the .txt document and at the right side the content of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob, os
import pandas as pd

input_d = '../in'
filenames = []
blobs = []
for pathname in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_d, '*.txt'))):
    with open(pathname, 'r') as txtfile:
        filename = os.path.basename(pathname)
        filenames.append(filename)
        blob = ' '.join(txtfile.read().splitlines())
        blobs.append(blob)

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':filenames, 'text_blob':blobs})
```

Pandas data frames can be created in [many ways.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#object-creation) One of them is passing a dict object.